# ArcGIS JavaScript: Uncaught Type Error

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to use the Identify Task with the ArcGIS JavaScript API, similar to this [example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/tasks-identify/). I am getting the following errors when I try to add my map service to the code.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lods' of null

and

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of null

I parsed down the code I am using to what is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Identify Task - 4.3</title>

<style>
html,
body,
#viewDiv {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.3/esri/css/main.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.3/"></script>
  <script>
  require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/layers/TileLayer",
  "esri/tasks/IdentifyTask",
  "esri/tasks/support/IdentifyParameters",
  "dojo/_base/array",
  "dojo/on",
  "dojo/dom",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(
  Map, MapView, TileLayer,
  IdentifyTask, IdentifyParameters,
  arrayUtils, on, dom
) {

  var identifyTask, params;

  // URL to the map service where the identify will be performed
  // in the stackexchange post I am using an ArcGIS map service that exhibits same behavior as my URL
  var soilURL =
    "https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Population_World/MapServer";

  // Add the map service as a TileLayer for fast rendering
  // Tile layers are composed of non-interactive images. For that reason we'll
  // use IdentifyTask to query the service to add interactivity to the app
  var parcelsLyr = new TileLayer({
    url: soilURL,
    opacity: 0.85
  });

  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "osm"
  });
  map.add(parcelsLyr);

  var view = new MapView({
    map: map,
    container: "viewDiv",
    center: [-118.3, 34],
    zoom: 15,
   minZoom:12,
   maxZoom:18
  });


  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how I can get the map service to display and not throw the errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The major problem I see is that you are trying to use a `MapService` as a [TileLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-TileLayer.html).  Since the `MapService` you specified is not tiled, try using the [MapImageLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-MapImageLayer.html) type.  This will stop throwing the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lods' of null` (because tiles have Levels of Detail).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Identify Task - 4.3</title>

<style>
html,
body,
#viewDiv {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.3/esri/css/main.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.3/"></script>
  <script>
  require(["esri/config",
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/layers/MapImageLayer",
  "esri/tasks/IdentifyTask",
  "esri/tasks/support/IdentifyParameters",
  "dojo/_base/array",
  "dojo/on",
  "dojo/dom",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(
  esriConfig, Map, MapView, MapImageLayer,
  IdentifyTask, IdentifyParameters,
  arrayUtils, on, dom
) {
  esriConfig.request.corsEnabledServers.push("sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com:6443");
  var identifyTask, params;

  // URL to the map service where the identify will be performed
  // in the stackexchange post I am using an ArcGIS map service that exhibits same behavior as my URL
  var soilURL =
    "https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Population_World/MapServer";

  // Add the map service as a TileLayer for fast rendering
  // Tile layers are composed of non-interactive images. For that reason we'll
  // use IdentifyTask to query the service to add interactivity to the app
  var soilsLyr = new MapImageLayer({
    url: soilURL,
    opacity: 0.85
  });

  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "osm"
  });
  map.add(soilsLyr);

  var view = new MapView({
    map: map,
    container: "viewDiv",
    center: [-118.3, 34],
    zoom: 15,
   minZoom:12,
   maxZoom:18
  });


  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try building your `IdentifyTask` against the `soilsLyr`

Comment: I changed the TileLayer to MapImageLayer and made the call to `new MapImageLayer` and it works now. Thank you!